# ¿Como crear campo especificador de identidad con CodeFirst?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Nesecito crear una tabla donde mi clave primaria es el campo Email y nesecito un campo especificador de identidad que se autoincremente en 1 de nombre Id con EntityFramework CodeFirst

Escribi la siguiente clase con la que creo mi tabla desde C# ...todo bien menos el campo Id no es autonumerico no se incrementa, cada vez q creo un registro toma el valor de cero (0).

Como puedo solucionar esto ???

Mi Clase ...

```
  [Table ("Cliente")]
    public class Cliente
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "INT")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime FechaRegistroPrueba { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime FechaActivacionPrueba { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "DATETIME")]
        public DateTime FechaActivacion { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
        public bool Estatus { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "BIT")]
        public bool EstatusEnvioNotificacion { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: porque el mail tiene que ser la key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definir el campo `email` como `key` de la tabla es incorrecto si prevees que tendra otro campo Id que sera incremental

Debes definir el `Id` como `key` de la tabla y que demas sea `identity` para que se autoincremente al insertar

Despues puedes definir al campo mail como `UNIQUE` para que no permita repetidos

[Code First Data Annotations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#index)

Analiza el titulo `Index`, entonces defines la propiedad como `[Index(IsUnique = true)]`

```
    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

de esta forma no permitira repetidos y estara indexado como lo seria la key de la tabla, pero sin ser la key

Answer (score 1):

Tal que así:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Column(TypeName = "INT")]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

No hay necesidad de definirlo como Key para que se autoincremente, pero si que es verdad que Email deberás definirlo como UNIQUE